# why Ajax request is not working with spring tag library

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I tried to submit form through Ajax but its not worked but
when i removed spring tag library than its worked fine..

so i want to know why Rest Api is not supports spring tag library

here is the ajax code for submit form

```
$("#change-password-by-otp").submit(function(event) {
            console.log("submitting user reset password form");
            event.preventDefault();
             var email="${emailFromUser}";
            console.log("hey hi--->"+email)


             $('.error-message').empty(); 
            $.ajax({
                type : $(this).attr('method'),
                url : $(this).attr('action'),
                data : $(this).serialize(),
                success :function(response, headers, HttpStatus)  {
                     if(response.validated){
                         $('.center-content').html('<h5 class="text-success">password is changed</h5>')
                        }else{
                              $.each(response.errorsMap,function(key,value){
                                $('.error-messages').append('<span  class="passworderror">'+value+'</span>'+
                                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" id= "remove-password"></span>');
                              });
                            }

                 },
                error : function(error){
                       console.log("error===>"+error)
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error massage but when i used Spring tag library, form summited by default and its not executed Ajax code, but without spring tag library above code is working fine.

Comment: Spring Tag library has nothing to do with Ajax working, is your button `change-password-by-otp` a submit type button?

Comment: yes it's type is submit